# Insert data in an array list java

Tags: java

I have two lists one is feature and has a placement number based on which i insert data in sorted list e.g if placement number is 5 data will be added in 5th position .i want to add data at 5th postion and to move data which was at 5th position to next index but in my case it just replace data at 5th position not move current data to next position

```
      for (int i = 0; i < featuredList.size(); i++) {

            int n = featuredList.get(i).getPlacementNumber().intValue();
            if (n < sortedList.size()) {

                    sortedList.add(n, featuredList.get(i));


            } else {
                sortedList.add(featuredList.get(i));
            }


        }
```

Comment: What types are `featuredList` and `sortedList`?

Comment: Use ArrayList function addAll and add a new list with your specified item http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(int,%20java.util.Collection)

Comment: Try to use LinkedList : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), from [add(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E))

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

Make your `sortedList` as ArrayList:

```
List<YourType> sortedList= new ArrayList<YourType>();
```

---

See the example http://ideone.com/L6hpsf

```
String s1 = "s1";
String s2 = "s2";
String s3 = "s3";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(s1);
list.add(s3);
list.add(1, s2);
System.out.println(list);
```

Output: `[s1, s2, s3]`

Comment: i have initialed but it replace data at index instead of adding data at a given index and moving the data to next index

Comment: Can you give use example and output/expected value  of  your program?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [LinkedList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html) to insertion or deletion between list for better performance then ArrayList :

```
private LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();

linkedList.add("1");
linkedList.add("2");
linkedList.add("3");
linkedList.add("4");
linkedList.add("5");

// insertion at 3 position
linkedList.add(2,"6");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example which may give you some clue and even easy to run :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Alisttest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
    a.add("1");
    a.add("2");
    a.add("3");
    a.add("4");


    System.out.println("a=> "+a.get(2));
    a.add(2, "Pankaj");

    System.out.println("a=> "+a.get(2));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("a=> "+a);
}

}
```